# How to get Multiple Threading.Timer instances Running in Harmony

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Hi there I've got a real pain in the proverbial problem with an app that runs multiple threading.timers as in:

```
'Instaniate the timer to refresh the memory cache of pi points (tags)
_tagRefreshTimer = New Threading.Timer(New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf TagRefresh), Nothing, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
'Instaniate the timer to check for new files to process
_fileCheckTimer = New Threading.Timer(New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf FileCheck), Nothing, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
'Instaniate the timer to check for dynamic setting changes
_settingsTimer = New Threading.Timer(New Threading.TimerCallback(AddressOf SettingsRefresh), Nothing, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
```

Each of the timers can be configured to run at different intervals:

```
_tagRefreshTimer.Change(_tagRefreshInterval, _tagRefreshInterval)
_settingsTimer.Change(_settingsRefreshInterval, _settingsRefreshInterval)
_fileCheckTimer.Change(_fileCheckInterval, _fileCheckInterval)
```

I expected that these timers, since they are running in separate threads, would run happily in parallel with each other; however, this has not proven to be the case in practice. What happens is that two of the three will run together, but for some reason the third does not get an opportunity to fire.  If I put a break point in the code, and wait for a few seconds, then continue, the third one sometimes does fire, however only at that point, thereafter it disappears into the background.

I'm wondering If I have some sort of race condition going on here, though I have to say as I mentioned at the start since threading.timers run in their own thread and in this context are not conditional on content from the main thread, I was simply not expecting this issue.  Anyone have any idea what is going on here and how I might circumvent it?

Comment: Have you read the Remarks section of [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to make sure that a Threading.Timer is the right timer to use in this case? The timers don't run in separate threads - the callbacks do. (P.S. it's Instantiate rather than Instaniate.)

Comment: Given the information you have provided, it *should* work. There's no reason why it wouldn't. Have you tried changing the order of the timer.Change calls and see if the results are the same? Or swapping the intervals between a working timer and a non-working timer?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your feedback.  Apologies for the typing error :-)

Comment: Djv: Yep tried these, however, I'm going to have a closer look at the timers this morning to see if I can get a closer handle on the circumstances surrounding the affected timer.  Will get back to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I've traced the problem to my attempts to pause each of the three different timers using 'Timeout.Infinite' under certain conditions from within the competing callbacks.  For example when the tag refresh was taking place I wanted to pause the file check process until the tag refresh had completed, and vice versa.   It seems that even though each of the timers was switched back on once the task was completed, something was preventing the timers from acting as expected.  Have cleaned up the code now and all timers are firing as expected and callbacks are completing as expected.  App is now functioning as intended so consider this query answered.  Thanks again for your input :-)

Kind Regards
Paul.